# unable to interact with input element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="hidden-fields hidden" style="display: block; overflow: visible;">
**<input type="password" id="current-password" placeholder="Enter Your Current Password">**
<div class="pass-guide-group">
**<input type="password" placeholder="New Password" id="new-password">**
<span class="pass-guide">Password must contain at least 8 characters and three of the following: upper case, lower case, number, and symbols.</span>
</div>
**<input type="password" placeholder="Confirm New Password" id="confirm-password">**
</div>
<div class="submit-controls" style="display: block; overflow: visible;">
*<input type="button" class="btn btn-inline btn-save-inline" id="savePassword" value="Save">*
<a href="#" class="edit-form btn-b btn-cancel-inline btn-inline" id="cancelPassword">Cancel</a>
```

****** it is my code *******

`_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@id='frmChangeUserPass']/div/input")).SendKeys("abc123");
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("new-password")).SendKeys("abc1231");
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("confirm-password")).SendKeys("abc123");
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("savePassword")).Click();`

**//wait for "password successfully changed" message to appear**

```
WaitElementVisbileById("cardholder-settings-success");
vaidationMessage = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("cardholder-settings-success")).Text;
```

I am using selenium WebDriver with c# bindings for automating change password functionality.

Im unable to interact with the input elements are bold in the above code. But the ones that are in italics can be interacted.

Comment: More of the page source, an error msg, and what code you've tried would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know what the problem was. But I got the solution. I had to clear the input box before inputting anything into it even if it was empty.

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is really interacting with the `input` elements, this won't help, but anyway the values you are sending to `new-password` and `confirm-password` are different:

```
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("new-password")).SendKeys("abc1231");
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("confirm-password")).SendKeys("abc123");
```

Comment: Is this really an answer, or just a comment? Maybe that is the test.

Comment: It is a possible answer. The question doesn't really specify where the problem is. I think changing password is never going to work if those two passwords are different.